# Laravel 419 after ajax post request with CSRF token applied

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I've been following this guide: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-keyword-density-tool-with-laravel/ and have found right at the end my app won't return any array. In fact when I click the submit button I notice I get a 419 console error. After checking most issues relate to the CSRF token but from check I have this is place properly.

Can anyone spot or guide me in the right direction so that my app returns something. It's not very advanced in fact it's a very simple application, but It's my first time using Laravel so any guidance is appreciated.

My index.blade.php (This contains the form and ajax request)

```php
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <form id="keywordDensityInputForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="keywordDensityInput">HTML or Text</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="keywordDensityInput" rows="12"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Get Keyword Densities</button>
    </form>
@endsection


@section ('scripts')
    <script>
        $('#keywordDensityInputForm').on('submit', function (e) { // Listen for submit button click and form submission.
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting
            let kdInput = $('#keywordDensityInput').val(); // Get the input
            if (kdInput !== "") { // If input is not empty.
            // Set CSRF token up with ajax.
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                $.ajax({ // Pass data to backend
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "tool/calculate-and-get-density",
                    data: {'keywordInput': kdInput},
                    success: function (response) {
                        // On Success, build a data table with keyword and densities
                        if (response.length > 0) {
                            let html = "<table class='table'><tbody><thead>";
                            html += "<th>Keyword</th>";
                            html += "<th>Count</th>";
                            html += "<th>Density</th>";
                            html += "</thead><tbody>";

                            for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                                html += "<tr><td>"+response[i].keyword+"</td>";
                                html += "<td>"+response[i].count+"</td>";
                                html += "<td>"+response[i].density+"%</td></tr>";
                            }

                            html += "</tbody></table>";

                            $('#keywordDensityInputForm').after(html); // Append the html table after the form.
                        }
                    },
                });
            }
        })
    </script>
@endsection
```

My master.blade.php (CSRF token in the head)

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Keyword Density Tool</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<style>
    body {padding-top: 5em;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

...

<main role="main" class="container mt-3">

    @yield('content')

</main><!-- /.container -->

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
@yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

My controller

```php
<?php 
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Html2Text\Html2Text;
    
    class ToolController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
           return view('tool.index');
        }
        
        public function CalculateAndGetDensity(Request $request) {
                if ($request->isMethod('GET')) {
        
                    if (isset($request->keywordInput)) { // Test the parameter is set.
                        $html = new Html2Text($request->keywordInput); // Setup the html2text obj.
                        $text = strtolower($html->getText()); // Execute the getText() function and convert all text to lower case to prevent work duplication
                        $totalWordCount = str_word_count($text); // Get the total count of words in the text string
                        $wordsAndOccurrence  = array_count_values(str_word_count($text, 1)); // Get each word and the occurrence count as key value array
                        arsort($wordsAndOccurrence); // Sort into descending order of the array value (occurrence)
        
                        $keywordDensityArray = [];
                        // Build the array
                        foreach ($wordsAndOccurrence as $key => $value) {
                            $keywordDensityArray[] = ["keyword" => $key, // keyword
                                "count" => $value, // word occurrences
                                "density" => round(($value / $totalWordCount) * 100,2)]; // Round density to two decimal places.
                        }
        
                        return $keywordDensityArray;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

and my routes

```php
Route::get('/tool', 'App\Http\Controllers\ToolController@index')->name('KDTool');
Route::post('/tool/calculate-and-get-density', 'App\Http\Controllers\ToolController@CalculateAndGetDensity');
```

and the error I get is this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Vrd.jpg

I have checked all otherwsie answer suggestions on stackoverflow but nothing I do seem's to get my any further. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Hm, you `POST` data, but check `isMethod('GET')`?

Comment: Hi, I've tried changing that to `POST` but still same error message.

Comment: In the developer console (F12) check go to the network tab and check the cookies the request is sending. Make sure it is sending the same cookie session cookie it received when the page was loaded